# Python: script is not writing the links from variable

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, terminal, macos-sierra

My script below...

I feel like I'm missing one line of code to make this work properly. Using Reddit as a test source to scrap sport links.

```
# import libraries
import bs4
from urllib2 import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://www.reddit.com/r/BoxingStreams/comments/6w2vdu/mayweather_vs_mcgregor_archive_footage/'

# opening up connection, grabbing the page
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

# html parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

hyperli = page_soup.findAll("form")


filename = "sportstreams.csv"
f = open(filename, "w")

headers = "Sport Links"

f.write(headers)

for containli in hyperli:
    link = containli.a["href"] 

    print(link)

    f.write(str(link)+'\n')

f.close()
```

Everything works except that it only grabs the link from the first row [0]. If I don't use the code `["href"]` then it adds all the (a href links) except that it also adds the word **NONE** to the CSV file. Using the 
`["href"]` would (I hope) just add the http links and avoid adding the word NONE.

What am I missing here?

Comment: `containli.a` is only the first link in `containli`. You need to use `containli.findall("a")` to get all of them, then loop over them.

Comment: @barmar I changed it to what you said, and I now get no results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the documentation [Navigating using tag names](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigating-using-tag-names):

> Using a tag name as an attribute will give you only the *first* tag by that name
>   
> ...
>   
> If you need to get all the `<a>` tags, or anything more complicated than the first tag with a certain name, you’ll need to use one of the methods described in [Searching the tree](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-the-tree), such as `find_all()`:

In your case, you could use `page_soup.select("form a[href]")` to find all the links in forms that have `href` attributes.

```
links = page_soup.select("form a[href]")
for link in links:
    href = link["href"]
    print(href)
    f.write(href + "\n")
```

Comment: That worked. How would I narrow my search within the links? like, if I wanted to omit reddit users (as the script adds every link possible which I do not want to happen).

Comment: Read the BS documentation to see all the ways you can examine and filter the data.

Comment: I've looked over that page serval times and did a google search which lead me to try certain parameters - none of them worked. There has to be an easier way to omit the rows that contain the word "reddit".

Comment: I found away to do it. Only question is, how can i add a series of words like so ("reddit", "/r/", "/passwords") --- `with open('sportstreams.csv') as f,open('sstream.csv', "w") as f2:
    for x in f:
        if 'reddit' not in x:
            f2.write(x.strip()+'\n')`

Comment: Maybe use a regular expression match against `x`. Or simply `if 'reddit' not in x and '/r/' not in x and '/passwords/' not in x:`